# How to Query SQL Server ReportServer to find Parent Child Reports

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am familiar with queries against the ReportServer database to find a list of reports, but I need something more tailored to find a list parent-child reports, or at least the child reports.  I have an SSRS report whose output is like this:

[parent report output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HT2AQ.png)

When the user clicks on the link, a second child .RDL is executed.

I need a query that I can run to identify the link of Reports that contain a child.

Answer (score 2):

A very interesting question. As you've no doubt discovered from digging into the ReportServer database each object on the server is represented by a row in the Catalog table, uniquely identified by the ItemID. And, as you've also no doubt found, there is no relationship between one Catalog item and another. So you can't write a regular SQL statement to query a report's drill-through/subreport(s).

A report only knows which subreport(s) to load when the RDL is being processed. So in order to get at the drill-through/subreport data we need to examine the RDL (which is really just XML). This is stored in the Content column of the Catalog table.

This bit of SQL should get you started.

```
with xmlnamespaces ('http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition' as rdl),
CatalogData as (
select ItemID, [Path], [Name], Content, convert(xml, convert(varbinary(max), Content)) 'ContentXml'
from [Catalog]
where [Type] = 2)
select ItemID, [Path], [Name], ContentXml, s.value('rdl:ReportName[1]', 'nvarchar(256)')
from CatalogData
cross apply ContentXml.nodes('//rdl:Drillthrough') as Subreports(s);
```

A few points to note:

- The double convert on Content as the column type is image
- Use of the reportdefintion xml namespace. You'll need to examine the XML generated from your own report server and replace as appropriate
- The xquery on the cross join is a descendant from the xml root. This is because a 'Drillthrough' tag can occur pretty much anywhere. Obviously this will impact execution times, especially if you have a lot of reports on your server. So you may want to add a where clause restricting the Path.
- You can find Subreports by altering the cross join xquery to '//rdl:Subreport'